# Hatch not changing the Breed Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

im trying to change the breed of my turtles at hatch but its just giving the mothers breed.

if more code is need please let me know. Thanks!

So, the edit is a more complete code and can be copy pasted. The idea is that if males (machos) find a females (hembra) then they should reproduce, and the new hatch needs to be either male or female. However this is not happenign, theres only females, i chagned the variables in such way that they reproduce alot, meaning that i should see at least one male spawn, but it doesnt.

```
 turtles-own[energia fecundidad vejez]

breed[machos macho]
breed[hembras hembra]

patches-own[alimento]


to setup
  
     resize-world 0 90 0 60
  clear-all
   ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 30 and
    pxcor >= min-pxcor and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 65
    set alimento random 100

  ]
 set-default-shape turtles "cow"

   create-machos 3

  [ set size 3        ;; easier to see
    set color gray
setxy random xcor random ycor
move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 65]
    set heading random 45 + 45
    set energia random 500
    set fecundidad 0
    set vejez 0
 ]

  set-default-shape turtles "cow"

   create-hembras 3

  [ set size 3        ;; easier to see
    set color black
    set xcor random 30
    set ycor random 60
move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 65]
    set heading random 45 + 45
    set energia random 500
    set fecundidad 0
    set vejez 0
 ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask machos [
        if energia >= 60 [reproducirse]
    set heading random 360
      fd 1
 set energia energia - 1
  ]
  ask machos [set fecundidad fecundidad + 1]
  ask machos [set vejez vejez + 1]

    ask hembras [
      if energia >= 50 [reproduccion_hembra]
    set heading random 360
      fd 1
 set energia energia - 1
  ]
  ask hembras [set fecundidad fecundidad + 1]
  ask hembras [set vejez vejez + 1]
  tick
end

to reproducirse
 

  ask machos[if any? hembras with [fecundidad >= 6][ set heading towards one-of hembras with [fecundidad >= 6]]
    ]

end

to reproduccion_hembra
  ask hembras [ if energia >= 50 [if any? machos in-radius 4 [ set energia energia - 60
       hatch 2  [set breed one-of (list machos hembras) rt random-float 360 fd 15
      set energia (100 + random 400)
  set vejez 0]]]]
  
end
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem? It is always important to do so also because often, in the process of preparing it, you will solve the problem yourself. On my NetLogo I created a toy model to try and reproduce the behavior you described (not posting it here because it could not be formatted properly in a comment, but it actually contains even less characters than the code you posted) but I cannot reproduce your problem: in my case, `females` hatch approximately 50% `males` and 50% `females`.

Comment: Matteo, great to see you again! I have edited the post to include code that can be copy pasted. The code is still not giving me a variety of breeds. Hope you can see the problem. good day

Comment: I saw the update but I am still unable to reproduce the problem: I copy&paste your code and, when agents reproduce, roughly half of them are females and half of them are males. You can check this by creating two reporters in the interface: one with `count hembras` and one with `count machos`. There are things that need to be fixed (although they are not part of this question), but the choice of breeds is not one of them as far as I can see on my side. PS: it is preferable that you switch the custom parts of your code to English when asking for help, as it will make it easier for others to read

Comment: Using the counter you are right both males and females are spawing. I changed the color of the hatched to make it clearer. what other problems you see? to polish this

Comment: You have a serious logic error in your sample code.  The procedure `reproducirse` is run by a `macho`, but inside the procedure you `ask machos` again. That causes ALL the `machos` to do this procedure, not just that one `macho`! It is not correct to use `ask` again, here. The procedure is already being run inside `ask`. The `reproduccion_hembra`  procedure has the same issue.